# Proper way in Mongo to update the value of a key without removing old values?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to get the following to work but `$set`'s not working. Scratching my head.

What we have in Mongo:

```
{
    _id: "123",
    mechanics: {
        engine: [
            "129hp",
            "300hp",
            "500hp"
        ]
    }
}
```

The object that we have in our javascript:

```
{
    mechanics: {
        brakes: [
            "30cm",
            "60cm",
            "90cm"
        ]
    }
}
```

How do you write the update query to make the Mongo doc look like this?

```
{
    _id: "123",
    mechanics: {
        engine: [
            "129hp",
            "300hp",
            "500hp"
        ],
        brakes: [
            "30cm",
            "60cm",
            "90cm"
        ]
    }
}
```

Doing `$set` on `mechanics` doesn't work because it erases `engine` and adds in `brakes`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you basically want is ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) which means that your update portion with [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) comes out like this:

```
{ "$set" : { "mechanics.brakes" : [ "30cm", "60cm", "90cm" ] } }
```

To process an object in JavaScript like you show into this form you would do something like this:

```
var upd = { "$set": {} };

var obj = {
    mechanics: {
        brakes: [
            "30cm",
            "60cm",
            "90cm"
        ]
    }
};

Object.keys( obj ).forEach(function(top) {
    Object.keys( obj[top] ).forEach(function(inner) {
        upd["$set"][ top + "." + inner ] = obj[top][inner]
    });
})
```

Which forms the update statement from the basic `obj` input and updates the database as you want.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I figured as much - you have to find a way to remove the parent keys of the `mechanics.brakes` object or only pass in the values into the Mongo operation. Just wondering if there was another operator or something in Mongo for only adding values but not replacing existing values.

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny There are [several update operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-field/) which all have the purpose of not overwriting other existing fields in the document. But "dot notation" with the full path to the element you want to update is what you need here.